# How can I make my navigation bar text bold?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I have a Master-Detail architecture, and I need to make the detail page's title text of the navigation bar bold. How can I do that the simplest way?

Here is some of my code:

```
    private void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.SelectedItem as MainMDPageMenuItem;
        if (item == null)
            return;

        item.ItemBorderColor = Color.Red; // Make a red frame around the selected item
        if (PreviouslySelectedItem != null)
        {
            PreviouslySelectedItem.ItemBorderColor = Color.FromHex("#00a8d5"); // Return the original color to the previously selected (now deselected) item
        }

        var page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType);
        page.Title = item.Title; // THIS IS THE TITLE I AM TALKING ABOUT

        Detail = new NavigationPage(page);
        IsPresented = false;

        MasterPage.ListView.SelectedItem = null;

        PreviouslySelectedItem = item;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was given a solution here:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/358994#Comment_358994

It is done by using TitleView:

```
        var page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType);

        var titleView = new Label
        {
            Text = item.Title,
            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
            TextColor = Color.White,
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#00a8d5")
        };

        NavigationPage.SetTitleView(page, titleView);
```

Answer (score 0):

For Android part, you could implement this feature by add the following in your `Resources\values\styles.xml` file:

```
<style name="ActionBar.nameText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">58sp</item> <-- Could delete this line
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Then, add it in your `Resources\layout\Toolbar.axml`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:companyApp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" 
    companyApp:titleTextAppearance="@style/ActionBar.nameText"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I use only UWP. IS there any equivalent for UWP?

Answer (score 0):

For IOS, you should simply do this. in **FinishedLaunching** of IOS project you need to put this `UINavigationBar.Appearance.TitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes()
            {
                Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(18.0f, UIFontWeight.Heavy)
            };`

before `LoadApplication(new App());`

Comment: Thanks, but I use only UWP. IS there any equivalent for UWP?